# Thymeleaf (th:each + th:selected) : accessing variable in selected attribute from each loop

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, server-side, template-engine

I would like to make option tag selected, if some list contains value from each loop. But there are some troubles with accessing variable from loop in selected attribute.
Here is my code:

```
<option th:each="facility: ${facilities}" th:value="${facility.id}" th:text="${facility.name}" th:selected="${apartment.facilities.contains(facility.id)}"></option>
```

Next code also does not work: `th:selected="${#lists.contains(apartment.facilities, facility.id)}"`

It works fine with `th:selected="${apartment.facilities.contains(SOME_DIGIT)}"` and `th:selected="${facility.id == SOME_DIGIT}"`. What's wrong?

Comment: For that you need to implement `th:if` condition inside your for-each loop.

Comment: I need to have all values from loop and some of them should be selected.

Comment: I'm guessing that `facility.id` and `apartment.facilities` are different types? One is an int, one is a string?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: there were different types. List contained int values, but the value type, I have checked on contains, was long.